# Flask-login with Apache virtualhost redirect error?

Tags: python, apache, flask, flask-login

I have a flask application that requires login authentication using flask-login to do the session handling. The application is using VirtualHost in apache, and the root url is `/myapp` for instance. When I hit a URL that requires login (for instance `/myapp/admin`), I get the desired login form and page, but then it redirects to `/login` instead of `/myapp/login` and I get a 404 error URL not found.

If I host the application at `/` instead of `/myapp` in the apache configuration, everything works as expected. Is there a setting for flask-login that would fix this, or another workaround?

My settings and login view are as follows:

```
login_manager.login_view = "login"
```

```
@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate():
       #do login stuff
    else:
        flash("Bad username and/or password!")
        return render_template("login.html", form=form)
```

And here is the VirtualHost directive for apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    #ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain
    WSGIScriptReloading On
    WSGIScriptAlias /myapp /envs/myApp/myapp/myapp.wsgi
    WSGIDaemonProcess myapp threads=5 user=user1 group=user1
    <Directory "/envs/MyApp/myapp/">
            WSGIProcessGroup myapp
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Does it work if you change it to `login_manager.login_view = "myapp/login"`?

Comment: Nope, that points to the name of the function/view that does the login, not the url

Comment: Ah, my bad. I've not used flask much. I'm somewhat confused by how you're using the apache `VirtualHost` directive. Do you mean that you have a directory on your filesystem with the path `/myapp`, or that you have a directory inside your web root with the name myapp? Could you post your VirtualHost directive?

Comment: No worries, I edited and added the vhost directive...